# How can I replace words in a sentence while still keeping punctuation in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I want to search through a message's contents and replace certain words with ones that match the ones that have translations.

Example input:
'I took a selfie with my bae next to a tardis. yolo!'

Filtered output:
'I took a self-portrait with my loved one next to a tardis. carpe diem!'

My code is translating the words, but only the words that do not have extra punctuation attached to the words like '.' and '!'. i.e. it translates to: 'I took a self-portrait with my bae. yolo!'

I am starting with an object of the words and their translations:

```
let blacklist = {
  'selfie': 'self-portrait',
  'yummers': 'delicious',
  'outchea': 'are out here',
  'bruh': 'wow',
  'doge': 'pug',
  'cilantro': 'soap',
  'bae': 'loved one',
  'swag': 'style',
  'yolo': 'carpe diem'
};
```

Here is my code to translate the words:

```
const message = 'I took a selfie with my bae next to a tardis. yolo!'

translate(message) => {
  let wordArray = message.split(' ');
  for(let i = 0; i < wordArray.length; i++) {
    if(blacklist.hasOwnProperty(wordArray[i])){
      wordArray[i] = blacklist[wordArray[i]];
    }
  }
  console.log(wordArray.join(' '));
};
```

Comment: You can use `.split(/\b/)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you an easier approach. Using `RegExp` object you don't have to care about the punctuation equality.

```js
let blacklist = {
  'selfie': 'self-portrait',
  'yummers': 'delicious',
  'outchea': 'are out here',
  'bruh': 'wow',
  'doge': 'pug',
  'cilantro': 'soap',
  'bae': 'loved one',
  'swag': 'style',
  'yolo': 'carpe diem'
};

const message = 'I took a selfie with my bae next to a tardis. yolo!';

function translate(message) {
  return message.replace(/selfie|yummers|outchea|bruh|doge|cilantro|bae|swag|yolo/g, match => blacklist[match]);
};

console.log(translate(message));
```

Comment: Very clean! However, how does the "match" work? I can't find it in the docs.

Comment: `RegExp` is okay in this case but not scaleable (for example if the array grows).

Comment: @ColinSygiel The match is an argument for the second argument (which is a callback function) in `replace` function. It replaces matched element with specified element returned by that function. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace

Comment: @ColinSygiel: it's worth looking at the MDN docs for [Arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) as well.

Answer (score 1):

Check out this snippet!

```js
function translate(words) {
    var arrayWord = {
      selfie: 'self-portrait',
      yummers: 'delicious',
      outchea: 'are out here',
      bruh: 'wow',
      doge: 'pug',
      cilantro: 'soap',
      bae: 'loved one',
      swag: 'style',
      yolo: 'carpe diem'
    };

    for (var key in arrayWord) {
        words = words.replace(new RegExp(key, "ig"), arrayWord[key]);
    }
    return words.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + words.slice(1);
}
var translatedString = translate("I took a selfie with my bae next to a tardis. yolo!");
console.log(translatedString);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.split(/\b/)` to split the string on a word boundary

Here is an example:

```js
var blacklist = {
  'selfie': 'self-portrait',
  'yummers': 'delicious',
  'outchea': 'are out here',
  'bruh': 'wow',
  'doge': 'pug',
  'cilantro': 'soap',
  'bae': 'loved one',
  'swag': 'style',
  'yolo': 'carpe diem'
};

var message = 'I took a selfie with my bae next to a tardis. yolo!'

function translate(message){
  return message.split(/\b/).map(w => (blacklist[w] || w)).join('');
};
 
console.log(translate(message));
```